# Questions / Tags about commercial products

Tags: support, product-support

I am wondering if the following has a place on StackOverflow or not:

There is a library written in JavaScript which is proprietary and which can only be used in the context of a certain server product which is also proprietary.

There is a community of customers and partners using this product and asking for substantial support for the scripts they write. (Not for the API or the library, so they would be on-topic in general) This type of support is not provided by the company that provides the product.

My question is, can Stack Overflow be a place where the people of this community can ask and answer their questions? Even if the topic is not of interest for a bigger public group of people? Or would this be an misuse of the SO platform?

I am not quite sure if this is "in the limits" of what is described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

I also saw some questions about this here on meta but most of them address open products.

Comment: What *kind* of *"substantial support"*? If they have legitimate programming questions that happen to require a particular, proprietary environment, I don't see that as being a problem. But they would have to meet the usual site guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest limit is the question needs to be on-topic for Stack Overflow - which means it is about a specific programming problem.

The presence of a tag does not automatically make questions on-topic, but if the question is on-topic, then questions about the product are probably ok.  How wide-spread or how niche the library is isn't really relevant if the questions otherwise fit on SO.

But keep in mind that questions still need to meet our normal question quality guidelines.  They need to be clear and focused, and they should not just be "Can someone write me a script to do `x`".

Similarly, asking for help on a specific script that isn't working can be on-topic.  But "find my bug" questions rarely go over well.  If someone has a bug or a script isn't working like they think it should, then it is important that they still ask a good question.

The first bullet in the [help center on-topic guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is important to that class of questions:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay that helps. What i meant was, they are usually on-topic because they always adress very specific programming problems like "look what i did, it doesn't work, why?"

Comment: @Chris I expanded my answer to cover the troubleshooting type questions better.